# Press ENTER each time Vim starts

Tags: startup

Each time Vim (v8.2) starts, it shows a subset of my key bindings, and awaits a keypress, like this:

```
n  <Space>     * za
n  ,<Space>    * :nohlsearch<CR>
n  Q           * <Nop>
Press ENTER or type command to continue"
```

In GVim on Windows 10, it shows a tiny dialog window with such a message that must be clicked away before the main window opens.

While searching for the cause of the problem, I read that my `.vimrc` might have a syntax error or that bindings are overwritten by other modules and vim warns about it, but I was never able to pinpoint the source. Using MacVim, no such messages occur when using the same `.vimrc`.

What is causing these messages?

Comment: You'll have to actually add your .vimrc. Start by commenting out everything, and reenabling bit by bit though. You'll find whatever region is responsible relatively fast taht way

Comment: @Zoe Thanks for keeping me looking in the vimrc, I found the problem after all. Seems like I bound a special character (|)?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to use `<Bar>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I should have kept looking in the `vimrc`, the error was caused by the following line:

```
nnoremap | ,
```

That should have probably been a different key ...

Comment: You might have to use `<bar>` if you really want | in a mapping anywhere

Comment: This will run the `:nnoremap` command and then `:,` since `|` is used to separate commands, like `;` in the shell and many programming languages. `nnoremap` without arguments will print all mappings (resulting in the ENTER prompt). As mentioned, you should use `<Bar>` in mappings if you want to map it. See `:help map-bar`.